# Image to ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

I have the json file in Internet.This file consist field "image",this field have url for the image.Question:How I can put images to ListView with 2 text field? How put text fields,I already know,but how put images...
I saw solutions with AsyncTask,but I alredy have one class extented AsyncTask.
MainActivity class below,maybe it can be helpul.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private Context context;
    private static String url = "https://fierce-citadel-4259.herokuapp.com/hamsters";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private ListActivity activity;
        public ProgressTask(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }
private Context context;
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success){
            if(dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,jsonlist, R.layout.list_item,new String[]{TITLE,DESCRIPTION,IMAGE},new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.description,R.id.image});
setListAdapter(adapter);


        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
           JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            for(int i =0;i<json.length();i++){
                try{
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtitle = c.getString(TITLE);
                    String vdescription = c.getString(DESCRIPTION);
                    String vimage = c.getString(IMAGE);
HashMap<String,String > map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(TITLE,vtitle);
                    map.put(DESCRIPTION,vdescription);
                    map.put(IMAGE,vimage);
                    jsonlist.add(map);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/). It's pretty easy.
In Android you can use an ImageView to display an image. This is the element you should pass as a parameter to the Picasso statement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can download images into `ImageView`s, but because the `ImageView`s are recycled with the `ListView`, there are some special considerations.

Here is an article that will give you the guidance to code image downloads for the exact situation you have:

[Multithreading For Performance | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

You should also check out the Picasso image library.